# Generate unique 12 letter alphanumeric string from two primary keys of table in php

Tags: php, algorithm

I have two tables: `category(cat_id type int,cat_name)` and `books(book_id type int,cat_id)`. When I assign a book to a user he will get a `book code`. I want to form this book code containing 12 alphanumeric characters and it must originated from the `cat_id` and `book_id`. Also I should be able to decode the code to get the `cat_id` and `book_id`. Any idea?.

Comment: What is the data type of cat_id and book_id?

Comment: @nhahtdh both are of int type.

Comment: what is the length of cat_id and book_id

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi both are primary keys and auto increment from 1 .

Comment: I meant the max-length to be displayed. Are you going to use up all the 2147483647 or even the unsigned one?

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi see the question--12 letter alphanumeric from two integers.

Comment: A book already has a cat. so using both bookid and catid seems a bit ambiguous to me.

Abby means the max size of the integers. so what is the max value for book_id and the max value for cat_id. it is quite important to know.

Comment: And also, how hard should it be to break the code, or doesn't that matter?

Comment: @nvanesch can you tell how to create such a code from 10,15(cat_id,book_id respctvly) ? leave the database structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here you go...

this can handle max signed integer types. and produces no more than 12 characters.

```
$firstId = "2147483646";
$secondId = "2147483646";
$firstBinary  = str_pad(base_convert($firstId, 10, 2), 31, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$secondBinary  = str_pad(base_convert($secondId, 10, 2), 31, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$finalBase36 = str_pad(base_convert($firstBinary.$secondBinary, 2, 36), 12, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
var_dump($finalBase36);
```

**update:** sorry i made a mistake.. this should do the trik with updated code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler approach by using HEX but you need to decide how many digits to be used for books and how many for categories.

For example, I suggest to use 8 for books and 4 for categories which is like.
by using hexadecimal one, the max record is FFFFFFFF FFFF, where you can use up all the unsigned int for books (max. 4294967295 books) and 65535 categories.

Practically, `LPAD(HEX(book_id), 8, '0')` for the first 8 digits and `LPAD(HEX(cat_id), 4, '0')` for the last 4 digits.

so the book code you want can be done by `SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(HEX(book_id), 8, '0'),LPAD(HEX(cat_id), 4, '0')) FROM books`

To retrieve back:
`SELECT UNHEX(substr(code,1,8)) as book_id, UNHEX(substr(code,9,4)) as cat_id FROM bookcode WHERE id=1`

If you want a larger set of data in the book codes, you may try a base36 or even base62(case-sensitive) encoding for both items. Such encoding is requiring your own code of user procedures.

Comment: for more info: php base 36 conversion: var_dump(base_convert($firstId.$secondId, 10, 36));

Comment: @nvanesch I didn't notice there is a php tag. ^^"

Comment: PHP has more useless functions than anyone can imagine :D

Comment: I meant that I supposed I am not allow to use php to finish it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `int` type is 32-bit unsigned integer. 2 `int` combined will have 2^64 unique values, which is approximately 1.844e19.

If we use only lower or upper case English alphabet, plus digits, then there are 36^12 = 4.738e18 different values, which is not enough to create a one-to-one mapping from the 2 keys to the book code.

If you add 5 more characters to the set of characters for the book code, there will be 41^12 = 2.256e19 different values, which is just enough to create the one-to-one mapping.

However, the conversion will involve division and multiplication, where integer overflow might happen when you convert from book code back to the keys.

If possible, you may want to extend the set of characters to 64 characters: 26 * 2 English alphabet in lower/upper case, 10 digits and 2 special characters (possibly `_` or `-`), where you can play with bit shifting - which is safe from integer overflow. For the unused bits, you might want to fill it with random data, which is seeded by the 2 keys; the reverse construction will ignore the (fixed) positions with random bit.